# jQuery Ajax post is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I know that there is a lot of questions like this out there, but I have been surfing them and other website for like 4 hours trying to figure this out. I am trying to get main.js to post the data via ajax and then the php should echo that data. If it does not work, it will echo "null". It keeps echoing "null" instead of "John". I know that the jquery and main.js links work, I have tested them. Here is main.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.post("index.php", { test: "John"} );
});
```

And here is the php part of index.php:

```
<?php 
    $var = "null";
    if(isset($_POST['test'])) { 
    $var = $_POST['test'];
    }
    echo $var;
?>
```

I hope you can solve my problem, and thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in this code where you are checking the value returned by index.php. If you are trying to post from ajax and then view the data on a php page, you should be storing it as a session variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the callback function with the response from the server.

```
$.post( "index.php",{ test: "John"}, function( data ) {
  alert(data);
});
```

Or you can do something like this:

```
 $.post( "index.php",{ test: "John"})
  .done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
  });
```

Please check the documentation [Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: Did you try to call index.php and watch for the response... You can use Postman to verify if the server respond.

Comment: If you have more javascript code may be the error is not in that block of code, be sure if your web server is runing.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot

jQuery

```
var available agent = 1;
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "your-url",
    data: available_agent,
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success:  function(data){
        owner = data['round_robin_agent'];
    },
    error : function () {
       alert("error");
    }
});
```

PHP Script

```
public function round_robin() {
    //Do your work
    $round_robin_agent = 'rob';
    $results_array = array(
        'round_robin_agent' => $round_robin_agent
    );
    return json_encode($results_array);
}
```

Comment: Make sure that you are calling in the jquery library or else this will not work. Also you need to alert or console.log owner to see rob returned.

Answer (score 0):

Download HTTP Trace chrome extension, traceback ajax call and share a screenshot.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/http-trace/idladlllljmbcnfninpljlkaoklggknp